# How to integrate underscore into mean.io

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, bower, browserify, mean.io

I'm developing a mean.io module and I wish to use underscore in client code, specifically - in a controller file under

```
packages/myModule/public/controllers/
```

It is my understanding I can pull it in with bower. I did so - it's under bower_components. The next step is unclear:

how can I have underscore sent to the client? Also, how to make it available locally via:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

I gave grunt-browserify a shot. Couldn't get it to work because jshint barfed a bunch of errors - maybe something to do with underscore needing to be jshint'ed with a 'global' flag(?)

What is the proper clean and maintainable way to make underscore available to client code?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding underscore to the asset.json file.  If you are using .4 it's in the config folder.

Comment: This look like a promising start. Problem is bower_components/build/js/dist.min.js is not created or sent in dev mode, meaning when NODE_ENV != 'production'. Any idea what part of the framework does it? Also, once it's somehow in what do I need to do in order to 'require' it (as above)?

Comment: It should be getting aggregated automatically via the asset.json file.